# Least brute force way to see how many groups of numbers in a group of numbers add to a given number in C++ or Python

Tags: c++, python, numbers

The title is probably a little ambiguous.

There is a given number.

There is a set of numbers all less than the given number and greater than zero.

I want to know how many different combinations of adding numbers there are that equal the given number.

For example if the given number is 14 and the numbers in the set are 7, 7, 7, 6, 4, and 4.
There would be  4 combinations. (7+7, 7+7, 7+7, 6+4+4)

I don't really care what language the solution is in, but I would prefer C++ or Python.

Comment: This is equivalent to the [subset-sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is NP-complete. The article gives a fairly good dynamic programming solution.

Comment: @isbadawi: Good call.  I was about to post that this is a knapsack problem, but Subset Sum is a more specific class.

Comment: This is the knapsack problem. It is NP-complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be discouraged by the claims that this is NP-complete.  The Wikipedia article on Subset Sum linked by @isbadawi mentions a 1999 paper by Professor David Pisinger with an algorithm that sounds like it would work with your existing constraints in linear time: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196677499910349 .  It's $31.50, but that sounds like a bargain if you really need to solve this problem well.